# Streaming replication between postgresql 9.2 and 9.3

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.3

Does anyone know if it's problematic to have a postgresql 9.3 slave setup to do streaming replication from a postgresql 9.2 master?

Comment: Did you ever give this a try?  If so I'd like to know how it went.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In general, log shipping between servers running different major
>   PostgreSQL release levels is not possible. It is the policy of the
>   PostgreSQL Global Development Group not to make changes to disk
>   formats during minor release upgrades, so it is likely that running
>   different minor release levels on primary and standby servers will
>   work successfully. However, no formal support for that is offered and
>   you are advised to keep primary and standby servers at the same
>   release level as much as possible.

It is quite plain in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/warm-standby.html) - you may try but don't be surprised if it does not work.